# How might a construct a URL for an Event List of a specific calendar using the Solspace Calendar plugin?

Tags: solspace, plugin-solspacecalendar

I am using the Solspace Calendar plugin for Craft CMS. I need to construct a URL for the Events listing template for a specific calendar group. For example, I want to use the Events template, but only for the Academic calendar, so that I exclude events in the athletics or faculty calendars.

None of these work.

`http://localhost/calendar/events/academics` or `http://localhost/calendar/events/calendar/academics`

Help, please?